# How can I find out if my program has the right to create a file in a directory?

Tags: .net

If I have the right to create a new file in the program directory I want to create the file there, if not I want to create the file in the program's AppData folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to create the folder and catch the ensuing exception: everything else isn't safe because since Windows is (more or less) a real-time systen, between the moment where you test for the rights and the moment of folder creation, the rights might have been changed. Consider the following potential, critical event chain:

- User is about to change the folder rights
- Application tests for folder creation rights: test for rights successful
- User commits the changes
- Application tries to create the folder

Comment: Please don't downvote without leaving a justfication. How should I know what in my posting was deemed wrong?

Comment: I'll use this method for now although I don't like it.

Comment: @null: If it's any consolation, I don't like it either.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [FileIOPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx) to determine if your application has particular permissions for a file / folder.

From MSDN:

```
FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.None);
f.AllLocalFiles = FileIOPermissionAccess.Read;
try
{
    f.Demand();
}
catch (SecurityException s)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Message);
}
```

EDIT: A more explicit repsonse to your question could be something like :

```
private string GetWritableDirectory()
{
  string currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory; // Get the current dir
  FileIOPermission f = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, currentDir);
  try
  {
    f.Demand(); // Check for write access
  }
  catch (SecurityException s)
  {
    return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) ; // Return the appdata (you may want to pick a differenct folder here)
  }
  return currentDir; // Have write access to current dir
}
```

Comment: weiqure doesn't say if he's using c# on Windows - but I didn't know this.

Comment: Yep. Deleted my Try-Catch answer

Comment: I don't really understand this. If I ran this code with my programme being in C:\Windows, wouldn't it complain?

Comment: @weique - not if you had write rights to C:\Windows, which you would if you were logged in as an admin

Comment: I am not logged in as an admin so I shouldn't have write rights to C:\Windows. I also tried it out on Windows 7 and I got the same result. All I'm doing is 'Console.WriteLine(GetWritableDirectory());'.

Comment: You must have write access to c:\windows if you copied the executable in there?

Comment: I copied it there with another account.